# Where to add an error message to a program finding UPC validation

Tags: java

I need help finishing this code up, I have all of the logic to it and I understand what my code needs to do, I'm just unsure where to add this piece of code to my program and keep everything else running fine.

If i put the code before the while loop without the while wrapped in the else then it works perfectly fine but it throws an exception out of bounds rather than printing the error message and continue on.

If I put the code before the while loop with the while all wrapped in the else it first prompts and after the upc code is input it then prompts again and works fine, but I don't get why it's not doing anything on the first prompt?

thanks in advance!

updated code**  it now has trouble with the upc being larger than 12 and if the user enters a blank line, it doesn't print the goodbye statement or the error message, however it does print the error message if the upc is less than 12?
any suggestions would be appreciated greatly!

```
    public class Project06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
        String upc = keyboard.nextLine();               

            while (upc.length() <= 12 && upc.length()>0) {          

            int odd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(2))
                    +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(4))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(6))
                    +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(8))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(10));
            int even= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(1))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(3))
                    +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(5))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(7))
                    +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(9));
            int sum= odd*3+even;
            int checkDigit= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11));


            if (sum%10 !=0) {
                int subtract= 10-(sum%10);


                if (subtract==checkDigit) {
                    System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +subtract);
                    System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ checkDigit);
                    System.out.println("UPC is valid");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                    upc= keyboard.nextLine();
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +subtract);
                    System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ checkDigit);
                    System.out.println("UPC is not valid");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                    upc= keyboard.nextLine();
                }

            if (upc.length() < 12 || upc.length() > 12){
                if (upc.equals("")) {
                System.out.print("Goodbye!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("ERROR! UPC MUST have exactly 12 digits ");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                    upc= keyboard.nextLine();
                }
        }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone happens to have any suggestions, without adding any code or switching into methods, please feel free to help me learn my way through java! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look over the following code.  I have put the input in a method, so you only have to do it once. The upc=null causes the checksum calculation to be skipped and ask for a new upc. I also added an error message if the sum%10 is not right.
Cliff

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class upc
{
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String upc = inputLine();


        while ( upc == null || upc.length() == 12 ) 
        {      
         if(upc != null )
         {

        int odd= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(2))
                +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(4))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(6))
                +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(8))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(10));
        int even= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(1))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(3))
                +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(5))+Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(7))
                +Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(9));
        int sum= odd*3+even;
        int checkDigit= Character.getNumericValue(upc.charAt(11));


        if (sum%10 !=0) {
            int subtract= 10-(sum%10);

            if (subtract==checkDigit) {
                System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +subtract);
                System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ checkDigit);
                System.out.println("UPC is valid");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
            }  else {
                System.out.println("Check digit should be: " +subtract);
                System.out.println("Check digit is: "+ checkDigit);
                System.out.println("UPC is not valid");
                System.out.println();
             } // if (subtract==checkDigit) 
            upc = null;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Bad sum.  (sum%10 !=0) = "+(sum%10)+" != 0!"); // WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN HERE?
        }
         } else  upc = inputLine(); 
    } // while
        System.out.println("End while");
} // main

public static String inputLine()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
    String upc = keyboard.nextLine();               

    upc = upc.trim();  // removes any leading and trailing whitespace 
    if (upc.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println(" UPC: "+upc.length()+", '"+upc+"'");
    if (upc.length() < 12 || upc.length() > 12)
    {
           System.out.print("ERROR! UPC MUST have exactly 12 digits ");
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");

     }  else {
           return upc;
     }
    return null;
}
} // upc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and writing that code for me, I can't use it because we haven't gotten into methods yet but I will look over the logic and see if I can change my code! much appreciated!

Comment: @Jason Parks Your welcome. Well main is a method, so you do use them.  If you find the information useful, please accept the answer. Cliff